# How to rewrite a Java program using Stream API methods, such as filter and map?

Tags: java, functional-interface

I have a small program that iterates over an array of strings and then prints either true or false depending whether the string from array is included into another string.
How to rewrite this program using Stream API methods, such as filter and map?

```
    String mainString = new String ("qrfghjtysd");
    String container = new String ("qre fgh ty np");
    String[] smallStrings = container.split("\\s++");
    StringBuilder res = new StringBuilder();
    Arrays.stream(smallStrings).  forEach(str -> {
        if (mainString.contains(str)) {
            res.append("true" + System.lineSeparator());
        }
        else {
            res.append("false" + System.lineSeparator());
        }
    });
    System.out.println(res);
```

Answer (score 3):

It seems like you want to transform each string `s` in the array to either "true" or "false" depending on `mainString.contains(s)`, and then join them together with new lines as the separator. The transformation can be done with a [`map`](https://docs.oracle.com/en/java/javase/18/docs/api/java.base/java/util/stream/Stream.html#map(java.util.function.Function)), and the joining can be done with the [`joining`](https://docs.oracle.com/en/java/javase/18/docs/api/java.base/java/util/stream/Collectors.html#joining(java.lang.CharSequence,java.lang.CharSequence,java.lang.CharSequence)) collector.

```
String res = Arrays.stream(smallStrings)
    .map(s -> Boolean.toString(mainString.contains(s)))
    .collect(Collectors.joining(System.lineSeparator(), "", System.lineSeparator()));
```

Like your original code, this adds a trailing new line to the resulting string. If you don't care about the trailing new line, you can just pass a single `System.lineSeparator()` argument to the `joining` collector, calling [the other overload](https://docs.oracle.com/en/java/javase/18/docs/api/java.base/java/util/stream/Collectors.html#joining(java.lang.CharSequence)).

Answer (score 3):

I would suggest something like this:

```java
final String mainString = "qrfghjtysd";
final String container = "qre fgh ty np";
final String res = Arrays.stream(container.split("\\s++"))
    .map(mainString::contains)
    .map(String::valueOf)
    .collect(Collectors.joining(System.lineSeparator()));
System.out.println(res);
```

Answer (score 1):

```
String mainString = new String ("qrfghjtysd");
String container = new String ("qre fgh ty np");
String[] smallStrings = container.split("\\s++");
StringBuilder res = new StringBuilder();
Arrays.stream(smallStrings).map(str -> mainString.contains(str)).forEach(flag -> res.append(flag + System.lineSeparator()));
System.out.println(res);
```

Answer (score 0):

try use "anyMatch":

```
String mainString = new String ("qrfghjtysd");
String container = new String ("qre fgh ty np");

boolean result = Arrays.stream(container.split("\\s++"))
                .anyMatch(s -> s.equals(mainString));
```